# C# dynamic query builder with SQL variables configurable

Tags: c#, sql

Am developing a Prototype where in i can access the SQL server dynamically.Table names and column names should be configurable at run time.

Eg: If am selecting a table or inserting records i should pass those values to a **Prototype Class** with table name,column name and parameters. and the class should take care of the rest.

Am trying to build that class.

Advice on the recommended steps to start.

Thanks

Comment: To put this in a context, what is this for? With abundance of ORMs and flexibility of sql dml, I have trouble imagining what the thing you are describing would be useful for. Is it a homework?

Comment: My idea is to build the query dynamically including table name, Column name.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @ColName nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @TableName nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @ColName2 nvarchar(4000)
DECLARE @Parameter nvarchar(4000)
set @TableName='tblTest'
set @ColName='ID'
set @ColName2='colValue'
set @Parameter=1

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(4000)
SET @sql = ' SELECT '+@ColName+' from ' + @TableName+ ' where '+@ColName2+'='+@Parameter
exec(@sql)
```

this is what i am doing. you can pass the above given parameters to a stored procedure and that will do a trick

Answer (score 0):

Maybe That is Useful ...
//Method

```
 public void insertCheque()
            {

         try {     

            SqlParameter[] param = new SqlParameter[5];
            param[0] = new SqlParameter("@IdBankChequeBook", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[1] = new SqlParameter("@IdBankChequeType", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[2] = new SqlParameter("@IdBankChequeStatus", SqlDbType.Int);
            param[3] = new SqlParameter("@TransType",SqlDbType.Int);
            param[4] = new SqlParameter("@ClientID",SqlDbType.Int);
```

//send sql parameter to stored procedure

```
 SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQuery(Connecting.LCM, CommandType.StoredProcedure, "InsertBankCheque",param); 



        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }   
    }
```

//Stored Procedure Related

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go      
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertBankCheque]    
@IdBankChequeBook int ,
@IdBankChequeType int ,
@IdBankChequeStatus int ,
@TransType int ,
@ClientID int ,
As
    Insert into BankCheque
    (
    IdBankChequeBook,
    IdBankChequeType,
    IdBankChequeStatus,
    TransType ,
    ClientID )   
     values 
        (
        @IdBankChequeBook,
        @IdBankChequeType,
        @IdBankChequeStatus,
        @TransType,  
        @ClientID )
```